# Strapi - Deleting admin user - what happens to orphaned data?

Tags: strapi

Simple question that I cannot find in the docs: if an admin user is deleted, what happens to orphaned data (entities created or owned by that user?).

- Is the orphaned data cascade removed?
- If not, how is this handled in the database?

For example, if one of the users is an author of articles. Are the articles also deleted if the user is removed? Honestly, it would be silly is this were the case, but wanted to check before I press the trigger.